# GWT refresh modifications

Tags: gwt, build, refresh, reload

I'm new to GWT and therefore have a lot of "code and see how it behaves" going on. I'm wondering what are the minimal actions to take to load the modifications in my web browser. For example when I work on the xml I can just refresh my page. So when do I need to perform these and why:

1. Refresh browser
2. Reload web server
3. Re build app
4. ???

Comment: By xml you mean an UiBinder template?

Comment: @Igor Yes, the *.ui.xml template. I got the bad habit of just calling it The xml because of it's extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*1. Refresh browser*

You need to do this whenever you've made code changes in UiBinder or any other client side code.

*Reload web server*

This needs to be done when you've made any changes to the server side classes. This only works if you're using the embedded Jetty in Dev Mode (not if you're using -noserver).

*Re build app*

You only need to compile the app when you're getting ready to deploy it or you want to show someone. This could also be required if you want to test the app in a browser that doesn't have the GWT plugin.

Comment: Also for "Rebuild app": when you are switching to an external server (`-norserver`), you need to build/compile the whole app and copy it over to a directory where your new server can serve it from. Note that this has to be done *one time* - after that you are back to refreshing the browser ;)

Comment: Yeah, good point. As long as you're only changing client code. However, when changing server side code with -noserver, you'll need to redeploy the server code.

Answer (score 0):

When running the app in development mode, making code changes in UiBinder or client side code the changes will be visible in the browser after a simple refresh.

**But** you will not see the error logs in GWT's "development mode" window unless you reload the server. So, by just refreshing the window you might miss some simple mistakes and you app will block with no notifications.